# JavaScript await for AJAX before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a race condition when clicking update on an inline grid edit with kendo ui.

On save I am executing the following function on save:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
   // This needs to run after the save has finished           
},
save: function (e) {
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Admin/OperatingCentre/GetById?id=" + e.model.OperatingCentreId,
            success: function (data) {
                e.model.OperatingCentreName = data.Name;
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Admin/Division/GetById?id=" + e.model.DivisionId,
            success: function (data) {
                e.model.DivisionName = data.Name;
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Admin/OperatingCompany/GetById?id=" + e.model.OperatingCompanyId,
            success: function (data) {
                e.model.OperatingCompanyName = data.Name;
            }
        })
   );
}
```

What I am after is to await the $.when function as the grid is not waiting until it is calling databound, and therefore the e.model.OperatingCentreName etc. are not being set in time to show in the grid.

When adding await this also doesn't help:

```
save: async function (e) {
    await $.when(
```

Any adivce would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to use .then()

Comment: `save: async function (e) ...`

Comment: `$.when(...).then(()=>{/*do your stuff here*/})`

Comment: All responses I have found have used .then/.done etc, but that doesn't help me here, I want the save function to wait until $.when is complete, otherwise the databound function is called before assigning...

Comment: Changed question code to show what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
dataBound: function(e) {
    // This needs to run after the save has finished           
  },
  save: function(e) {
    $.when(
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/OperatingCentre/GetById?id=" + e.model.OperatingCentreId,
        success: function(data) {
          e.model.OperatingCentreName = data.Name;
        }
      }),
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/Division/GetById?id=" + e.model.DivisionId,
        success: function(data) {
          e.model.DivisionName = data.Name;
        }
      }),
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/OperatingCompany/GetById?id=" + e.model.OperatingCompanyId,
        success: function(data) {
          e.model.OperatingCompanyName = data.Name;
        }
      })
    ).done(function(a1, a2, a3) {
      // a1, a2, and a3 are arguments resolved for the each of the ajax requests, respectively.
      // Each argument is an array with the following structure:
      //[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
      // here trigger the dataBound
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `async/await` should do the trick in your case

```
save: async function (e) {

    await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/OperatingCentre/GetById?id=" + e.model.OperatingCentreId,
        success: function (data) {
            e.model.OperatingCentreName = data.Name;
        }
    }),
    await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/Division/GetById?id=" + e.model.DivisionId,
        success: function (data) {
            e.model.DivisionName = data.Name;
        }
    }),
    await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/OperatingCompany/GetById?id=" + e.model.OperatingCompanyId,
        success: function (data) {
            e.model.OperatingCompanyName = data.Name;
        }
    })}
```

In this way you're blocking execution of the script until ajax call is executed and success callback is executed as well